# can you link in a css stylesheet to another in a different folder

Tags: html, css

My project hierarchy looks like:

```
main/
    style1.css
    stylesheet/
        style2.css
```

I want to include the stylesheet `style2.css` in `style1.css`, but `@import` doesn't work.

Comment: Can you update your question with your file structure and the code you used?

Comment: See [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29012734/3120193)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following folder structure :

[image]

---

In your **index.html** you link `main/styles.css` :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main/styles.css">
```

And in **styles.css**, which is in folder main, you import `stylesheet/stylesToImport.css` :

```
@import url('stylesheet/stylesToImport.css');
```

Note that, [as stated by the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#at-import), the following two syntaxes are equivalent :

```
@import url('stylesheet/stylesToImport.css');
@import 'stylesheet/stylesToImport.css';
```

Comment: Sorry, guys. I checked my code, and I had put `@import "stylesheet/stylesToImport.css";` instead of `@import ("stylesheet/stylesToImport.css");`. I left out the parentheses by mistake.

Comment: Please read carefully the answer. I didn't wrote `@import ('stylesheet/stylesToImport.css');` but `@import url('stylesheet/stylesToImport.css');`

Answer (score 0):

Just include the two stylesheets in your page header. There's no restriction on how many stylesheets you can import, but if you redefine a style the definition closest to the content will take precedence.

Comment: I don't want to have to include both those stylesheets in the header of every page I make. I'd rather include them in the one stylesheet, and then link that one to my HTML documents.

Comment: You can definitely do this - I caution against it because included files within included files gets messy quick.